# Is it possible to have Zero Downtime when publishing a Website to Azure App Services (deployment slot) + autoswap

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We've been using Azure App Services for a while and for us, it's pretty good.

When we manually do a SWAP (production <-> staging, deployment slots) we get a white screen of death with some `WEBSITE INACCESSIBLE` error in the middle of the deployment. After a bit of time, the site feels like it's warmed up and it's back online again.

Is there a way to avoid IIS (we're assuming IIS causes this) from doing this? Also, this needs to be automated ... so we we WebDeploy our new codem it pushes this up, warms up, then swaps.

NOTE: we also use STICKY SLOTS

We *think* the sticky slots are causing this 'reboot/bounce' to occur at the start of the swap..

So - is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try to activate "Custom warm-up before swap". It could solve your issue.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing#custom-warm-up-before-swap

Comment: Hmm. ok. i get what you are trying to suggest. That possibly the home is not hit or doesn't warm the site up (which it should if it is hit by azure during warmup)

Comment: Also consider "Swap with preview (multi-phase swap)" (currently in Preview). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing#swap-with-preview-multi-phase-swap

Comment: Swap with Preview requires manual step/intervention :( Was trying to do all of this automated (yep, we're happy with the risk associated with that).